# How do I recreate these images of the activity series in latex?

Tags: overleaf

The images I want to recreate -

[image]

[image]

I was thinking of creating a table but I'm not sure whether creating the vertical line in a tabular environment is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `tabular` inside of a `tikzpicture` can do the trick (but there are most likely other possibilities as well, e.g., you could use a Ti*k*Z `matrix`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0]
    (list)
    {%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        Li\\Cs\\Rb\\K\\Ba\\Sr\\Ca\\Na\\Mg\\Be\\Al\\\\C\\\\Zn\\Cr\\Fe\\Cd\\Co\\
        Ni\\Sn\\Pb\\\\H\\\\Sb\\As\\Bi\\Cu\\Ag\\Pd\\Hg\\Pt\\Au
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  \draw[->,-Stealth,very thick]
    (list.south west) ++(-1,0)coordinate(tmp)
    -- (tmp|-list.north)
    node[above]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Increasing\\activity\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    (0,0) node[inner sep=0] (list)
      {%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
          F\\Cl\\Br\\I
        \end{tabular}%
      }
    (list.south east) ++(1,0) node[inner sep=0,anchor=south west] (weak)
      {weakest oxidizing agent, least readily becomes reduced}
    (list.north-|weak.west) node[inner sep=0,anchor=north west,text=orange] (strong)
      {strongest oxidizing agent, most readily becomes reduced}
    ;
  \draw[->,-Stealth,very thick,orange]
    (strong.south west) ++(5pt,-5pt) coordinate(tmp)
    (tmp|-weak.north) ++(0,5pt) -- (tmp)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without extra Ti*k*Z you can do with `\uparrow` (and some trickery).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\templen}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\setlength{\templen}{(\widthof{Increasing}-\widthof{$\uparrow$})/2}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Increasing \\
  activity
\end{tabular} \\
$\hspace*{\templen}
 \left\uparrow
 \hspace*{\templen}
 \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
   Li\\Cs\\Rb\\K\\Ba\\Sr\\Ca\\Na\\Mg\\Be\\Al\\[1ex]
   C\\[1ex]
   Zn\\Cr\\Fe\\Cd\\Co\\Ni\\Sn\\Pb\\[1ex]
   H\\[1ex]
   Sb\\As\\Bi\\Cu\\Ag\\Pd\\Hg\\Pt\\Au
 \end{tabular}
 \right.$
\end{tabular}

\caption{Elements in order of increasing activity}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
F & \color{red!80!blue}strongest oxidizing agent, most readily becomes reduced \\
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Cl \\ Br \end{tabular} &
\color{orange}$\left\uparrow \vphantom{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Cl \\ Br \end{tabular}}\right.$ \\
I & weakest oxidizing agent, least readily becomes reduced
\end{tabular}

\caption{Something else}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]